# Querying Nested Type Map <string, timestamp>

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a sample table, let's call it table:

| id | events |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {requested=1719-05-08 11:11:11.111, created=1820-05-08 11:11:11.699, completed=1869-69-69 15:11:13.111} |
| 2 | {created=6969-01-01 09:01:01.466} |

I want to be able to query the completed date in each ID but not all ID's contain a completed timestamp.

What I've tried:

```
select events["completed"] as completed from table
```

My error: Column 'completed' cannot be resolved.

Desired Output:

| events |
| --- |
| 1869-69-69 15:11:13.111 |

Can someone assist please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
ELEMENT_AT(events, 'completed') as completed_at
from table

https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/map.html

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes escape a column name (if it has some invalid symbols in it), try passing string (with single quotes):

```
select events['completed'] as completed 
from table
```

Note that it will throw if key is not present in the map. You can use [`element_at`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#map-functions) if the key can be missing:

```
select element_at(events, 'completed') as completed 
from table
```